# Video player: HTML5 vs Youtube API

Tags: html, video, youtube

I need to display a video on a simple website (actually the video will be the only object), listen to the following events and store a timestamp (user's clock in millis) each time:

- Buffering completed
- First play()
- Pause()
- Resume()
- Stop() (meaning that the user watched the video entirely)

Compatibility: the users may open the website in any system (old browsers for example).

My question is: what technology do you recommend to achieve these requirements: native HTML5 (using the video tag) or Youtube API?

Bonus requirement: do not allow the user to move the video cursor forward or backward (the only operation allowed is pause/resume).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to meet the requirement of supporting older browsers, you will need to provide a Flash fallback as HTML5 video is not fully supported (see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=video)). The YouTube API will provide the fallback out of the box (in fact I think it defaults to Flash anyway).

If you plan to use HTML5 video you will need to make provision for the fallback yourself. Your best bet would be to use one of the popular HTML5 video libraries, many of which will handle this for you, and which provide a consistent API regardless of the delivery mechanism. [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) and [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) are both popular choices.

The other requirements are all fully realisable using either option. With the YouTube API I think you'll need to follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) to implement custom controls in order to limit the user to play / pause controls. The other APIs may allow you to more easily pick and choose from the controls provided out of the box (ie. to remove the scrubbar by configuration). In both cases, you will be able to capture all the events you list in your bullet points.

An advantage of using YouTube, depending on your requirements, is that the hosting of the video file is provided free by YouTube. Furthermore, it may suit you to have the video posted on social media as well as on your own website as it may lead to wider exposure.

Comment: is this still relevant in 2020?